# forEachで回したobjectの値を空の配列にpushしたい。

Tags: javascript, es6

forEachで回す配列のobject

```
[
    {
      value: 'ja', label: '日本語', locale: 'ja-JP'
    },
    {
      value: 'en', label: 'English', locale: 'en-US'
    },
    {
      value: 'cn', label: '简体中文', locale: 'zh-CN'
    },
  ];
```

引数で指定したlangの配列オブジェクトの値に{cv.label}ではアクセスできません。

```
  const emptyArr = [];
const arr = lang.forEach((cv) => (
  emptyArr.push({label: {cv.label}, value: {cv.value} })
));
```

欲しい結果

```
const arr = [
    { label: '日本語', value: 'ja' },
    { label: 'English', value: 'en' },
    { label: '简体中文', value: 'cn' },
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

オブジェクト初期化子でオブジェクトを生成する場合には、**オブジェクトのプロパティ名と、それに関連する値の組み合わせのリスト**とする必要があり、 `{cv.label}` や `{cv.value}` はエラーを発生させます。これは期待される出力結果を考慮すると、以下のように修正出来ます。

```js
const lang = [{
    value: 'ja',
    label: '日本語',
    locale: 'ja-JP'
  },
  {
    value: 'en',
    label: 'English',
    locale: 'en-US'
  },
  {
    value: 'cn',
    label: '简体中文',
    locale: 'zh-CN'
  },
];


const emptyArr = [];
const arr = lang.forEach((cv) => (
  emptyArr.push({
    label: cv.label,
    value: cv.value
  })
));
console.log(emptyArr);
```

また、今回の場合は `forEach` メソッドと `push` メソッドの代わりに `map` メソッドと分割代入を使い、以下のようにすることが出来ます。

```js
const lang = [{
    value: 'ja',
    label: '日本語',
    locale: 'ja-JP'
  },
  {
    value: 'en',
    label: 'English',
    locale: 'en-US'
  },
  {
    value: 'cn',
    label: '简体中文',
    locale: 'zh-CN'
  },
];

const arr = lang.map(({label, value}) => ({label, value}));

console.log(arr);
```